# How to write a case when like statement in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

```py
def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    grad = np.where(residual>0, -2*10.0*residual, -2*residual)
    hess = np.where(residual>0, 2*10.0, 2.0)
    return grad, hess
```

I want to write this statement:

```
    case when residual>=0 and residual<=0.5 then -2*1.2*residual
    when residual>=0.5 and residual<=0.7 then -2*1.*residual
    when residual>0.7 then -2*2*residual end )
```

however `np.where` cannot write &(and) logic . How do I write this case when logic in the `np.where` in python.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This statement can be written using [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html?highlight=select#numpy.select) as:

```
import numpy as np

residual = np.random.rand(10) -0.3 # -0.3 to get some negative values
condlist = [(residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5), (residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7), residual>0.7]
choicelist = [-2*1.2*residual, -2*1.0*residual,-2*2.0*residual]

residual = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=residual)
```

Note that, when multiple conditions are satisfied in `condlist`, the first one encountered is used. When all conditions evaluate to `False`, it will use the `default` value. Moreover, for your information, you need to use bitwise operator `&` on boolean numpy arrays as `and` python keyword won't work on them.

Let's benchmark these answers:

```
residual = np.random.rand(10000) -0.3

def charl_3where(residual):
    residual = np.where((residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5), -2*1.2*residual, residual)
    residual = np.where((residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7), -2*1.0*residual, residual)
    residual = np.where(residual>0.7, -2*2.0*residual, residual)
    return residual

def yaco_select(residual):
    condlist = [(residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5), (residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7), residual>0.7]
    choicelist = [-2*1.2*residual, -2*1.0*residual,-2*2.0*residual]
    residual = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=residual)
    return residual


%timeit charl_3where(residual)
>>> 112 µs ± 1.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit yaco_select(residual)
>>> 141 µs ± 2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

let's try to optimize these with `numba`

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def yaco_numba(residual):
    out = np.empty_like(residual)
    for i in range(residual.shape[0]):
        if residual[i]<0.0 :
            out[i] = residual[i]
        elif residual[i]<=0.5 :
            out[i] = -2*1.2*residual[i]
        elif residual[i]<=0.7:
            out[i] = -2*1.0*residual[i]
        else: # residual>0.7
            out[i] = -2*2.0*residual[i]        
    return out

%timeit yaco_numba(residual)
>>> 6.65 µs ± 123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Final check

```
res1 = charl_3where(residual)
res2 = yaco_select(residual)
res3 = yaco_numba(residual)
np.allclose(res1,res3)
>>> True
np.allclose(res2,res3)
>>> True
```

This one is about `15x` faster than the previously best one. Hope this helps.

Comment: How to write residual>=0?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. how to write How to write residual>=0?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the syntax `(condition1) & (condition2)` in `np.where()` calls, so you would modify your function's `np.where()` calls like so:

```
def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    residual = np.where((residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5), -2*1.2*residual, residual)
    residual = np.where((residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7), -2*1.0*residual, residual)
    residual = np.where(residual>0.7, -2*2.0*residual, residual)
    ...
```

The first argument is the condition to meet, the second argument is the value to use if the condition is met, the third argument is the value to use if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use vectorization since conditions are mutually exclusive:

```
residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype(float)
m1 = (residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5)
m2 = (residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7)
m3 = (residual >0.7)

new_residual = -2*(m1 *1.2 *residual + m2*residual + m3*2.0*residual)
return new_residual
```

This will have the following performances:

```
residual = np.random.rand(10000) -0.3
def speed_test(residual):

    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype(float)

    m1 = (residual>=0.0)&(residual<=0.5)
    m2 = (residual>=0.5)&(residual<=0.7)
    m3 = residual >0.7
    return -2*(m1 *1.2 *residual + m2*residual + m3*2.0*residual)

%timeit speed_test(residual)
123 µs ± 35.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```